# Delphi TWebBrowser: non-functional scrollbars on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, windows-8, scrollbar, twebbrowser

I'm trying to show normal scrollbars on a Delphi TWebBrowser running on Windows 8.

A TWebBrowser scrollbar on Windows 8 appears this way and they are not usable (it's not draggable a there isn't no arrows):

[image: TWebBrowser scrollbar on Windows 8]

This problem appears only on Windows 8 and 8.1 when TWebNrowser is showing a responsive website.

Is there any solution to have the normal twebbrowser scrollbar?

Many thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Metro style! The next Windows version promises to have not even scroll thumb :)

Comment: Make your own `IWebbrowser2` class.

Comment: @JohnLewis do you mean i've to reimplement all iwebbrowser2 methods? Why do i have to build this class?

Comment: I don't think that comment from John makes much sense. `IWebBrowser2` isn't even a class.

Comment: Have perhaps thought about using gestures. You can still use gestures even on systems without actual touch screen or touch sensitive pad using mouse. Naturally you are limited to single touch gestures in such case. But that shouldn't be problem for you as you would only need up-don swipe gesture. I know that this is not the best solution (hece why I only wrote a comment) but it would still be better than nothing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well then use `TWebbrowser`.

Comment: @John The asker is doing just that